I installed flatpak recently on my Ubuntu 24.04. When ever i try to run "sudo apt update" command on the terminal I get the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 2332 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

This show up 2-3 times each time i run 'sudo apt update'. Is this normal? What can i do to resolve it? I am facing this issue only after I had installed flatpak.

"Is this normal?" Maybe. Maybe not. Are you saying that the error goes away after a few minutes? If you do a graceful poweroff and restart, does the error go away? If the error message remains after restart, does the process number change?

The error remains 1-2 times I execute sudo apt update. The 3rd time I execute the command it works. Restarting the system does not resolve the error. This error started showing up after I installed flathub.

Since flatpack is a package management tool, I guess that it runs apt commands. For fairly obvious reasons, apt uses a lockfile to ensure that only one process at a time is doing package management. Your command will work if it happens to run while flatpack is not doing any apt stuff. I suggest that you just keep trying, or stop flatpack temporarily.

I am still new to linux. Can flatpak and snap coexist together?

AskUbuntu Etiquette: Your question seems currently unanswerable due to a lack of information. The purpose of comments is to encourage you to edit your question, improving the question until it is answerable. Comments are a poor format for responses and conversations. You will get better help faster if you use AskUbuntu the way it is designed to be used.

@jeffas Flatpack is a separate package management tool and does not use apt/apt-get/aptitude or their files once installed

@MuhammadOmarFarooq apt, snap, and flatpack can all co-exist together as they all use different install locations and packaging formats

Thanks user535733 and DanHolli for the flatpack clarification. I see from OP that the process holding the lock is packagekitd. So it would be that that's blocking other apt activity. I guess my comment does apply if you replace my references to flatpack with references to packagekit. I'll drop out now, as I'm not familiar with packagekit.

Since you said in the comments that the error persists after a reboot, it is likely that something failed during an update. Try running
sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

If (and only if) the lsof command does not list any files holding the lock, then it can be removed with
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock


This is the output I get:  "lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
Output information may be incomplete."

@MuhammadOmarFarooq those warnings are normal. As long as you don't see lines like this, it means nothing has the lock file open: COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME –
apt     221554 root    4uW  REG   8,17        0 524929 /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
